# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Hello I know there are questions similar to this problem but I just need a detailed explanation how can I remove the fatal error LNK1104. I'm using Visual Studio 2010

```
 1>------ Build started: Project: circle, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
        1>Build started 3/12/2016 1:52:30 PM.
        1>InitializeBuildStatus:
        1>  Touching "Debug\circle.unsuccessfulbuild".
        1>ClCompile:
        1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
        1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\Lamis\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\circle\Debug\circle.exe'
        1>
        1>Build FAILED.
        1>
        1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.93
        ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: The program `circle.exe` is probably still running. If a file is in use in Windows, you can't overwrite it. Exit the program (or kill the process) and try again.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg what do you mean by killing the process? what should I delete exactly

Comment: If your program doesn't seem to be running, and you think you have exited it, then go into the task manager and look for the process.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg where is this task manager? sorry for being annoying

Answer (score 2):

These are the common reasons:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s(v=vs.100).aspx

I find it happens sometimes for no obivious reason - when the process has not shutdown properly(?) and restarting Visual Studio appears to be the only solution.

Comment: in my case the issue was caused by the "Incremental Linking" feature... Disabled it for all the projects and tada :O